# How long to book a quarantine place if using test to release scheme

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, covid-19, airbnb

I booked a self-isolation place for 10 days for my trip to the UK. Due to some circumstances, my plans are postponed by 5 days. I made some bookings in UK after my 10 days isolation was supposed to end. I can not cancel/reschedule these booking.

I found out about the [Test to Release](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-test-to-release-for-international-travel) scheme where I can take a test on Day 5 of my arrival in the UK and can end my isolation if that result is negative. This would work perfectly for me as my trip is delayed by 5 days and I would be able to attend my other bookings.

Now my question is how long should I book a quarantine place before I travel to UK, should it be for just 5 days or 10 days? I prefer Airbnbs over hotels and no Airbnb provide any cancellation benefits during the middle of your stay.

Comment: It's pretty simple: what happens if you test positive on day 5?

Comment: Then you're going to have to self-isolate until day 15, so it'll be pretty difficult to plan for, full stop.

Comment: @jcaron this scenario is after I arrive in the UK, I may get notified even after full 10 days isolation that a close contact was tested positive so isolate again for 10 more days.
I am asking my question with regards to the passenger locator form and possible questions I may be subjected to by the entry clearance officer.

Comment: In England at least there is no longer a legal requirement to isolate from close contact exposure, although it may still be a good idea to do so.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over (as per the WHO)

Answer (score -1):

You should book for ten days.

The [How to quarantine](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-quarantine-when-you-arrive-in-england#how-to-quarantine) guide from the British government states the following:

"You must quarantine in one place for the full quarantine period, where you can have food and other necessities delivered."

and

"You are not allowed to change the place where you’re quarantining except in very limited circumstances...", followed by a short list, none of which would seem to apply to you.

Comment: The problem is that there is no refund option available for next 4/5 days if your day 5 test comes negative and you are free to end qurantine.

Comment: Yes. The UK isn't really 'open' to unvaccinated people from High-risk countries. The quarantine/test-to-release scheme is intended for people who *need* to travel - most of whom can stay with family or friends, or at least remain in once place. If you are able to, by far the best solution is to get vaccinated - If your country offers Jansen/Johnson and Johnson then you are considered fully vaccinated 14 days after your first (and only) dose.